# Spring Webapp with Hibernate, Annotation Driven, Issue after Issue, Source Code Link

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I am working on a Spring webapp using annotations and Hibernate.  One of the goals here is that the application be annotation driven (instead of XML) for all elements of the stack, which right now is just spring and hibernate.  Every solution from this and other questions I asked here about this code leads to a whack a mole style conflagration of issues, but this cant be that hard.  Please try this code!  It's much easier than us all going through a point by point exposition of stack traces.

A Github link is included, just git clone, maven clean package, and deploy to a suitable server such as Jetty, you can see all these traces in action.

Here is how this started: when firing up a webapp I got the following no class def found error:

```
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror L[org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
```

I am using Hibernate 4.3.4

```
<hibernate.version>4.3.4.Final</hibernate.version>
```

and am using the core jar

```
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here was the trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mobiusinversion.web.repositories.UserRepository com.mobiusinversion.web.services.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mobiusinversion.web.repositories.UserRepository.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
```

Now searching maven central, I see that class is in Hibernate 3.1, so now I've added that to my pom

```
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate4.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate3.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Along with the following required repository (which was a undocumented requirement, GROWL)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

However this leads to the following trace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mobiusinversion.web.repositories.UserRepository com.mobiusinversion.web.services.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mobiusinversion.web.repositories.UserRepository.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class com.mobiusinversion.web.spring.Config: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
```

Which after a number of stack traces contains

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:194)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:120)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:55)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
```

Since there is a lot going on here, and Stack traces get long, please, I ask you to try this code for yourself when looking at a possible solution.  The code is simple, self contained, and only requires maven and a suitable server.

https://github.com/mobiusinversion/SpringMVCWebApp

Help getting this working would be greatly appreciated.  It just seems like every solution to ever stack trace leads to another in whack a mole fashion.  Lets recap what we are try to do here:

Annotation based spring bean configuration
Annotation based hibernate configuration

Should be simple, right?

[UPDATE 4/4/14 4pm] The issue is now a HibernateException casue by no session bound to thread:

```
Caused by: 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
at com.mobiusinversion.web.repositories.UserRepository.createUser(UserRepository.java:26)
at com.mobiusinversion.web.services.UserService.createUser(UserService.java:21)
at com.mobiusinversion.web.controllers.BasicController.createUser(BasicController.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:717)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

After incorporating several good pieces of advice, here is the session bean construction in the spring config:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.mobiusinversion.web");
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

And here is where the error occurs.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Integer createUser(User user) {
        User mergedUser = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(user);
        return mergedUser.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: In the com.mobiusinversion.web.spring.Config class, I see org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.
This is deprecated in hibernate4. Instead you need to use org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Hi prasad, thanks, getting closer... maybe.  The container at least initializes, but when I try to access the sessionFactory I get this  `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
`

Comment: Here is the code with the change you recommended.  Do you have a moment to compile this and fire it up in Jetty?  https://github.com/mobiusinversion/SpringMVCWebApp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mobiusinversion/web/spring/Config.java

Comment: If so, try navigating to this url to try the sessionFactory injection http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCWebApp/createUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this command line [overlapping jars report](http://jhades.org/documentation.html#warreport) (a tool I made), there are two hibernate versions in WEB-INF/lib of the WAR:

```
>>>> Jar overlap report: 

hibernate-3.1.jar overlaps with hibernate-core-4.3.4.Final.jar - 
total overlapping classes: 494
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar overlaps with jta-1.0.1B.jar - 
total overlapping classes: 17

Total number of classes with more than one version: 511
```

Looking further in the POM with mvn dependency:tree we can see where the duplicates come from:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.4.Final:compile
...
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.1:compile
```

In this case there are two versions of hibernate added in the classpath, as hibernate is declared twice with different artifact names. The solution for this is to choose only one version of Hibernate, removing the other from the POM. The best would be to choose 4.3.4.Final because 3.1 is very ancient.

Comment: So the issue I faced with that is that `org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition` doesnt seem to be included in hibernate 4.  Am I missing the right place to find it?

Comment: I came to that conclusion looking on Maven central, that FilterDefinition was included most recent in 4.0.0-alpha  http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition%22

Comment: the class has changed package from `org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition` in hibernate 3 to org.hibernate.engine.spi.FilterDefinition` in hibernate 4. I think the best path forward is to remove hibernate 3 from the pom (it causes many duplicates, see report above), and regenerate the original problem before hibernate 3 was added.

Comment: for the original problem pre-hibernate 3 addition, can you post here the full stractrace with all caused by clauses, if 's too long could you use pastebin.com? That trace would give us which part of the  program was trying to use a hibernate 3 class, this seems the best direction to solve the problem

Comment: Ok, one moment, I will.

Comment: I removed the hibernate 3 deps and the FilterDefinition error is not there any more, but the no session bound to thread is.  Here is the pastebin  http://pastebin.com/6phKahat

Comment: looks like the problem is that `@Transactional` is not being applied, otherwise the transaction manager would have added a session to the current thread before the repository method `userRepository.createUser` is called. Try adding  `@EnableTransactionManagement` to the Config class, this will enable the use of `@Transactional`

Comment: Ok, getting much much closer to working software!!!!  Upon hitting the route `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCWebApp/createUser` I see in the logs `Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.name as name2_0_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into User (id, name) values (default, ?)
Apr 04, 2014 3:30:07 PM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logInfoEvent
INFO: Database closed` and I get a 406 response, `HTTP ERROR 406

Problem accessing /SpringMVCWebApp/createUser. Reason:

    Not Acceptable
Powered by Jetty://`

Comment: And in the directory specified for hsqldb I have `[david@david SpringMVCWebApp]$ ll ~/Jetty/jetty/db/
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david   90 Apr  4 16:32 myDB.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 1872 Apr  4 16:32 myDB.script
`

Comment: Let me see if this works with my local mysql, then this question could be considered totally answered and I can look into hsqldb on my own.

Comment: Hm, yep, this appears just to be related to returning an object, I think I need a json serializer, though I thought spring would automatically do that for some website I read.  Cheers, and thanks for all the help jhadesdev.

Comment: Who got the bounty?   ;)

Comment: jhadesdev ftw!  Thanks for all the help. This is actually a pretty piece of software now.  Should probably turn it in to a maven archetype :)))) Feel free to check it out and hack it up :)))  https://github.com/mobiusinversion/SpringMVCWebApp

Comment: Oh snap, I have to wait 17 hours to award bounty. Tomorrow it is

Comment: Glad could help, Happy friday!!

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.noclassdeffounderror L[org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition` is most likely because hibernate jar is missing from your classpath. Typically this happen if you forget to declare hibernate dependency on your maven pom.

To be able to inject HibernateSession, one simple way is to create [LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) and  autowire it to your class.

However some java container already has its own HibernateSessionFactory and this method might not be suitable.

Comment: Great thanks, I will try that.  Does that handle connection pooling for example?  If you want to see the example I'm working on, here it is  https://github.com/mobiusinversion/SpringMVCWebApp

Comment: Connection pooling is different matter to hibernate. You can use library like commons-dbcp or c3p0 on top of whatever datasource you have to make it pooled.

Comment: GerryTan, I have the hibernate jars in my classpath, but I am still getting the same error:  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 2 different jars of Hibernate
Or you have to configure the servlet container in order to use the web app classloader as first class loader
Moreover if I'm not wrong hibernate 4.3.X supports JPA2.1 spec so you should use this spec

Angelo