# @Value Annotation Syntax Issue

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations

In a Spring MVC anotation driven web app I have this as my container config

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mobiusinversion.web")
public class Config {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")   private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")               private String url;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")          private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")          private String password;
```

and in my application.properties, I have

```
 ################### JDBC Configuration ##########################
 jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
 jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/myDB;shutdown=true
 jdbc.username=david
 jdbc.password=
```

But when I deploy my war in the webapps directory of my jetty server, I get this error:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:389)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
```

So clearly this property is not getting processed.  How do I use the @Value annotation correctly to configure this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) bean in your context. For Java configuration, it has to be provided through a `static` `@Bean` method so that Spring has a hint that it is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and doesn't need (should be initialized before) the `@Configuration` bean.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

If you don't provide [`PropertySources`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html) directly through a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` setter within the `@Bean` method above, you have to provide the source in another way. For example, with [`@PropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mobiusinversion.web")
@PropertySource("classpath:your.properties")
public class Config {
```

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, the @PropertSourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer approached seemed to work.  When I tried the PropertySource approach I got the same error, though I though the application.properties was in the classpath 

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 404 Apr  4 08:15 src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: And I really like the `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` approach because it seems less "opaque" any ideas?

Comment: Oh actually, it looks like I needed to use both, one or the other did not seem to do it but together it seems to pick up the properties

Comment: The next error up is describe here.  Is there a chance I can get you to look at it for a quick second?  Maybe its a Hibernate 3 versus 4 issue?  Not sure  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750449/hibernate-zero-xml-config-in-spring/22751112

Comment: @david Sorry, I was away for a moment. `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` has a setter you can use to add `PropertySources`. You can either add them directly (and explicitly) there or use `@PropertySource` to add them implicitly.